# Meaning of 多い in 去年より４３％多い３４０万人

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 日本政府観光局によると、今年の１月から６月までに日本に旅行に来た外国人は１３７５万７３００人でした。去年より１７．４％増えて、半年の間に来た人の数では今までで最も多くなりました。
> According to the tourist board 13.8 million foreigners visited Japan between January and June this year. This is a 17.4% increase on last year and is the highest half year figure to date.
>
> この中で最も多かったのは韓国から来た人で、去年より**４３％多い３４０万人**が日本に来ました。
> Among these, the most numerous where people from Korea, and compared to last year ???? 3.4 million people came to Japan.

I can't understand how 多い is being used here. My literal translation is "compared to last year, the 43% numerous 3.4 million people...".

My first thought was that it referred to the increase in numbers, but 43% more Koreans than last year sounds too much. Then I thought maybe Koreans account for 43% of total visitors but the maths tells me it's only around 25%.

I think my first thought is the most likely but I'm far from confident. I'd be happier if it said もっと多い instead. Would this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.4 million people is the total number of Korean visitors, which is a 43％ increase compared with last year. The 43% increase is not too much because the relationship between China and Korea get worse, that is to say, Korean tourists are choosing Japan instead of China.

I think もっと isn't necessary.